# cURL downloads web page data, not file

Tags: curl

I am attempting to download some ephemeris data from NASA's CDDIS archive. I would like to download today's archive, which can be found at:

https://cddis.nasa.gov/archive/gnss/data/daily/2021/174/21n/brdc1740.21n.gz

This link will prompt the user to either download or open the data directly (opening it in a text editor shows it's a text file that is a collection of satellite data)

I wrote a script so that everytime someone runs it, they'll pull the most recent Ephemeris data. The curl command to pull the file that I'm currently using is:

```
curl -n -L  "http://cddis.gsfc.nasa.gov/archive/gnss/data/daily/$year/$day/$yr"n"/brdc""$day""0.$yr""n.gz" -o B.19n
```

My thinking is that the daily brdc file should be saved to the navigation file B.21n and I expect B.21n to contain plain text of satellite data. However, when I actually execute this command, and check the cat the contents of B.21n, all I get is a bunch of html data. A snippet of some of it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html lang="en" class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Earthdata Login</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Earthdata Login">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push(

      {'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'}

    );var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
      j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
      'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
```

How can I just download the file that lives at the aforementioned directory, which is the plain text file, instead of the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

That HTML looks like a login page, which is where I get redirected if I follow the link you provided. So it appears the data is not accessible via plain curl but requires some credentials.

There are docs available on that site which explain how to set up authorization and using curl/wget afterwards to retrieve data:
https://wiki.earthdata.nasa.gov/display/EL/How+To+Access+Data+With+cURL+And+Wget

Comment: I tried that. In fact, my .netrc file looks exactly correct. But no matter what I do, I still get redirected to the EarthData login page, which never redirects back to the actual download

Comment: Did you run the pre-authorization steps as well? Does the password have any characters that might need to be escaped?

Comment: I did, yes. Not sure why I keep getting sent to the login page.

Comment: I don't want to create an account to test, but I worked through those commands with incorrect credentials to see what it was doing, added `-vi` flag to curl and got `* Couldn't find host cddis.nasa.gov in the .netrc file; using defaults`. Can you confirm in the `.netrc` file you have `machine cddis.nasa.gov` as well and not just the urs.earthdata domain? And if you add the `-vi` flags, can you see basic auth being added?